# 'Pin' icon overlaps other content in review

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, design

In Chrome 54.x on OS X, on [this review task](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/93741) (although I assume it generalizes to anything with a pin change), I see the pin icon overlapping other content on all tabs:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report. Pushed a fix.